# plug in an asterisk based solution into my PBX network

Tags: asterisk, pbx

**Introduction**

my company has a 40+ phone system with both DECT and wired phones. the wired phones, coming from different periods have either UTP wiring or classic 4wire phone cabling. *NO SIP/VoIP* is in place

PBX is an Aastra 470.

voice comes from fiber router, enters a IP to ISDN converter and 4 UTP wires plug 8 lines into the PBX.

so far so good.

Now we are introducing a new ERP in the company, the ERP has an asterisk based *VoIP* solution to notify incoming calls into users pc, providing augmented info about the incoming call.

**The problem**

I'm wondering if is possible to introduce the asterisk based solution along with our current PBX (and setup in general). Infact, the asterisk solution will serve the customer care office with around 10 phones, while it will be of no interest for the other offices/building.

We do not want to rebuild the entire infrastructure for this, but the solution seems attractive for the customer care office. Of course we will update phones to VoIP solutions here.

**question**

is there a way to connect the 2 PBX, more generally, is it possible to use an asterisk based solution to manage a group of SIP phones and then , let say, daisy chain the current PBX, leaving everything else untouched?

the idea is to add this on top of the current infrastructure, avoiding big changes.

As no one here has expertise in this I'm asking for links/pointer or direct answers to clarify what could be done.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this in some way or another. Based on a very quick google, the Aastra 470 supports sip trunking.

You could create a SIP trunk on the Aastra 470, which then routes incoming calls to the correct phones, and outgoing calls either via the current connection, oir alternatively, via the SIP Trunk.

The ERP's box can be configured to forward calls to certain extensions, towards that SIP trunk, which would then be answered by the Aastra 470.

Is the Aastra 470 box managed by a 3rd party? You might be able to approach them for assistance, BUT in my experience, the proprietary providers don't like working outside of their own environment, as its a threat to their business.

TL:DR - Yes it's possible, given that both systems (apparently) support SIP.

Comment: so your suggestion is to create a SIP trunk between the PBXes. Just for clarity: where will I put the incoming line? into the ERP stuff that then forwards to the Aastra or vice versa?

Comment: You could do it either way. If you wanted to move away from the lines the PBX uses, then bounce the calls to the ERP system, if you want to carry on with the lines on the PBX, bounce the calls to the PBX.